# SQL Server : associate function to a column of a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, view, calculated-columns

I have a function that sending a code gets a description through various formatings, I need to use the function inside a view in four columns but rather than calling it in the query I would like to associate it as a computed column (so we don't have to modify the query/view if the function name or parameters changes so the DBA can manage it in the future...)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD ComputedColumn1 AS dbo.FunctionCall1(args......)
```

This adds a computed column to your table - and if the function is "deterministic", you can even add the `PERSISTED` keyword to it, so that the resulting value will actually be stored in the table (and the function isn't call every time you select a row).